# UITextField setVisible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, visible

I'm trying to set a UITextField visible or not but I can't find it in the doc. How to do it ?

I would like to use something like :

```
[myTextField setVisible:YES];
```

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
myTextField.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Absolutely... too much Java for me haha. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which is inherited by `UIView` that's why you missed it in the docs